# How to lock iPhone app in portrait orientation? (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, swiftui

I'm trying to submit my app to the App Store, but I received a notification that it must run as expected and properly display on iPad, but that requires me to lock it to portrait mode, so the UI doesn't get messy.
The boxes of "Landscape Left and Landscape Right" are already unchecked and I already tried changing the Info.plist file.

Here's how the iPad version gets glitchy:

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to simply let things work in landscape. But for that to happen, it definitely would be easier for us to help if you post some code. Obviously - at least to me - this `View` **can** fit fine in all aspects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forcing an "iPhone Only" app to run on an iPad.

It might help to activate the iPad app version and then look at what needs to be changed.

```
Target > General > Deployment Info> Check iPad
```

If you truly have a SwiftUI app it should not need a lot of work.